# Has anyone had a problem with python opening a file using dirname and have a double set of backslashes added to the file name?

Tags: dirname

I'm working on a simple application to upload an audio file to IBM Watson.  I'm developing in Python using Anaconda, and the Spyder IDE on Windows 10.  I'm running across an error I've not encountered prior.  When I run the application, the following command:

**with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'audio1.wav')**

is returning an error, and states the following:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: **'D:/Users/tperrodin/Documents/Python\./.\audio1.wav'**

When dirname returns the directory, why am I getting the following merged in the file: \./.\

Any idea why I'm getting this response?